# javascript to auto redirect to a different html only ONE TIME

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I'm trying to create a javascript that will redirect to a different html at exactly 9pm every night.  But the trick is that I only want it to redirect a single time.  I've created this one, and used it before with great success...the problem is that it permanently redirects one html to another during the specified time period:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();
var hour = d.getHours();
if(day == 3) //monday is 1, tuesday is 2, etc...
{
    if(hour >= 7 && hour <= 20) //military time duh
    {
        location.href = "washselection_wednesday.html";
    }
}
```

This is for a store front kiosk.  It sits at our home page all day long.  When we close at 9pm, I want the screen to automatically go to a different html that says that we are closed.  But I want to be able to get back to our home page if needed, so I can't use the above and permanently redirect to a different html.  It's almost as if I want someone to walk up to it and click on a certain webpage ONE time and then leave it.  But I want to automate the process with javascript instead.

Comment: Use `localStorage` to save a value that indicates whether you've already redirected before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localstorage` to save a value before the redirect, and then check it in the future.

If nothing has been saved to that key yet it will return `null`, which can be coerced into `false` here with `!!`

```
var redirectKey = 'has-redirected';
var hasRedirected = !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(redirectKey));

if(!hasRedirected){
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDay();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  if(day == 3) //monday is 1, tuesday is 2, etc...
  {
      if(hour >= 7 && hour <= 20) //military time duh
      {
          localStorage.setItem(redirectKey, true);
          location.href = "washselection_wednesday.html";
      }
  }
}
```